# Algorithm Question on finding the Median of nos

Tags: algorithm

Given a sequence of trillion real numbers on a disk...

> How would you compute the running
>   MEDIAN of every thousand entries i.e.,
>
> the first point would be the median of
>   a[0],....,a[999],
>
> the second point would be the median of 
>   a[1],...,a[1000],
>
> the third point would be the median of 
>   a[2],...,a[1001], etc. ?

Comment: "Median" and "mean" are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naive solution is actually not so bad, keep a sorted list of 1000 numbers in memory, and every time you step over to the next index remove `a[i-1]` from the sorted list and add `a[i+999]` to the sorted list.

Once you have that it's easy to compute the median in a sorted list.

The question is how do you do better?

Comment: Yes......  deleting a[i-1] and insert a[i+1] no. from the sorted list, would be too cumbersome!!

Comment: But is it really that bad? Those are both O(log n) operations in a skip-list for example. And that `n` would be referring to the 1000 not the trillion.

Comment: no it is not bad if these two operations lead to O(logn) operations..... any good articles on skip-list???

Comment: Actually there exists a solution with balanced BST as well.. Both insert and delete are O(logn) operations too.... I am trying to figure it out how Balanced BST can give us the median effectively.. any help??

Comment: I think there's a way to store a BST in an array so that the array is in order, isn't there?

Comment: No.... not in an array....  I was reading this link.... http://inder-gnu.blogspot.com/2008/01/find-median-in-continous-stream-of.html >>> And thinking of implementation.... but its looking difficult

Comment: Do you know how to use C++ STL.... I have just started learning STL Library..... they say that it can be implemented using multi-set

Comment: I think that's a map of one to several elements (A->{B,C}, C->{D,E}, ...) So each entry would represent a node and its children.

Comment: ohh... this looks difficult to implement... By the way I understood the algorithm to find medians using Balanced BST....

Comment: I used this applet http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~goodrich/dsa/trees/avltree.html to understand the concept.......

Comment: Lets say we have array 11,15,10,12,20,18,16,19,25,28,22

Comment: and we keep only 5 elements in the BST... so when we bring first 5 elements into BST >> we search for the median O(logn) time.... and then we slide the window i.e. delete 11 and insert 18 i.e. delete a[i-1] & insert a[i+1] in the BST which individually gives O(logn) time

Comment: Therefore in total finding the medians of 5-5 elements each in the array result to O(nlogk) -- k = 5 in our case, time algorithm....

Comment: but thinking of implementing it now.... can you give me a start.... I dont know how to build balanced binary search tree.. :(

Comment: I haven't implemented anything like that in a while, I think you're better off finding an example online.

Comment: Ya oks.... Anyway thanks for your time... I have started implementing using Maps in STL Library/C++.. This is awesome!! :) Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Maintain a max heap that stores the smallest 500 of the 1000 numbers and maintain a min heap that stores the largest 500.